# Modal adding/removing

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
 <!-- hero  -->
      <div class="hero">
        <div class="banner">
          <h1>Modal</h1>
          <button class="btn modal-btn">open modal</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of hero  -->
      <!-- modal  -->
      <div class="modal-overlay">
        <div class="modal-container">
          <h4>
            Some lorem
          </h4>
          <button class="close-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- end of modal  -->
```

CSS:

```
.modal-overlay {
  /*Some css codes to modify overlay*/
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
}
.open-modal {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

JS:

```
const btnModal = document.querySelector('.modal-btn');
const overlayModal = document.querySelector('.modal-overlay');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
function openModal(){
  overlayModal.classList.add('open-modal')
}
function closeModal(){
  overlayModal.classList.remove('open-modal')
}
btnModal.addEventListener('click',openModal)
btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', closeModal)
```

1. Is it the most efficient way for modals?
2. How .open-modal overwrites .modal-overlay's properties? Sometimes it worked for me, sometimes not. What do I need to give attention?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is. People usually use `display: block` and `display: none`. But `visibilty` also okay.
2. Your class aren't removed. You can try to use, if this resolve your problem

```
element.style.display = 'block' //
```

Here some references https://gomakethings.com/two-ways-to-set-an-elements-css-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see people sometimes use height:0 method, sometimes display:block method, do not know if in professional cases one of these ways is the most suitable.